# Generating default config.ini for an Eclipse RCP projekt

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, configuration-files

I have an Eclipse RCP projekt which I have to export as "deployable plug-ins and fragments" and then create an installer, which works fine. After installing, the program won't start. I have added some entries to the config.ini file which was generated automatically and atleast the login-screen was shown.

I want that eclipse generates the config.ini file automatically based on the configurations that I enter into an input mask. Therefore I have added a config.ini.product file to my project. However, if I export the project, create an installer and install it, the config.ini file is the same as before, with entries missing.

If I go to the eclipse documentation, it seems to me that the config.ini.product file (which is then used to generate the config.ini file) is only used when I export my application as "Eclipse product". I this true or am I confusing something? How can I get eclipse to generate a config.ini file with the appropriate entries?

These are the entries that I added afterwards, that resulted in atleast showing the loggin screen of the application:

- osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,\
- org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,\
- org.eclipse.core.runtime@start org.eclipse.equinox.ds@4:start,\
- org.eclipse.equinox.event@5:start,\

It is a migration from Eclispe 3.0 to 4.4. So now I'm using Luna.

**Edit 1**
I am now trying to export the plugins as "Eclipse product". In the Overview tab of the config.ini.product file I can add under "Product" -> "Product" and "Application" the corresponding classes. I also added the plugins which make up the application in the dependencies tab. But now if I want to export it as "Eclipse product", it says "The product's defining plug-ins could not be found." I don't really understand this error-message, because I added the plug-ins in the dependency tab.

Comment: Using 'deployable plug-ins and fragments' generates something that is intended to be installed in an existing Eclipse, a config.ini makes no sense for this so there is no way to generate it.

Comment: So my assumption was correct. The former build process was that the plugins where exportet as "deployable plug-ins and fragments" and then they where building an installer using inno setup 5. Now, if I am exporting the plugins as "Eclipse product", do i get a standalone application like the one we had before with an install wizard which installs the product and creates an .exe?

Comment: Product export gives you a directory or zip file containing everything needed to run the RCP (except a JRE). The latest Eclipse Mars builds can come with an installer but I don't know how that is built (might be using Maven + Tycho).

Comment: *Edit 1* seems to be asking a whole new question, if with the help @greg-449 and I has not been sufficient, perhaps you need to create a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and someone is sure to help. But at the moment the question is too much like asking for debugging help without enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent set of [tutorials](http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/p/tycho-articles.html) on creating and building a project with Eclipse, Maven and Tycho. You have not spoken about how you are building as part of your build system, but if you are moving from Eclipse 3.0 to a (much!) more modern Eclipse a lot of new options are available for you.

The tutorial is very good in that you don't need anything as everything is built up in stages.

When you get to [stage 6 of the tutorial](http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/tycho-build-6-building-products.html), it will show you how to make an Eclipse Product, and the key thing at that stage is the `yourname.product` file has in it the information on how to generate and configure a proper `config.ini`.

A quick rundown on what you need to do is:

1. Create a new product file. `File` -> `New` -> `Other` -> `Product Configuration` and press `Next`

[image: step1]

2. Fill in the wizard.

   1. Enter a location (existing project root folder would be normal)
   2. Enter a name
   3. Initialize the file content. This is the first pass where your config.ini will be created. You can probably choose `Create a configuration file with basic settings`. The second choice of `Use an existing product` may be useful to you as your product may be very similar to an existing one you already have (e.g. `org.eclipse.platform.ide`). Finally the third choice, `Use a launch configuration`, allows you to create the product file from an already created launch configuration. So if you have been tuning some launch configuration already you should be in luck with that option.

[image: step2]

3. Configure your config.ini

   1. Open product file
   2. Choose `Configuration` tab
   3. Press `Add Recommended...`
   4. Press OK
   5. Edit configuration for your needs

[image: step3]

### "The product's defining plug-ins could not be found."

This error message means that in the `yourname.product` file, in the Overview tab, the Product listed can not be found. A product is Eclipse has two sides to its definition. First is in the `plugin.xml` of a plug-in project, specifically it is extending the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

For example, in the `Overview` tab you might have `myproductplugin.product` as the `Product` (see screenshot below), you would in the `myproductplugin` project's `plugin.xml` have the following contents:

```xml
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench"
            name="My Product Name Here">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="My Product Name Here">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
```

You can get the `plugin.xml` contents written for you by pressing the `Synchronize` link (see screenshot).

[image: overview]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the steps as described but it doesen't work. I even added a new configuration-file based on my existing run configuration. The values in the product definition input fields are right, but when I click on "Synchronize this configuration with the product's defining plug-in" I get the error message that the plug-ins could not be found. I get the same error message when I try to export it as "Eclipse product" using this configuration-file. That's weird.

Comment: More details needed then, what appears in the `Product` field? Have you tried pressing `New...` next to Product to see if you create a new `Product` if that one works?

Comment: I found the error. There was a dot in the ID of extension with the point "org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications". Therefore I could not use the ID in the product configuration. When I clicked on "new", instead of using the ID which was not possible because of the dot Eclipse just put "product" as ID. Now I have to adapt the packaging, but then it will work fine. Thank you.